# Alt key command in Intellij for Windows

Tags: intellij-idea, alt-key

I've mapped some functions in IntelliJ IDEA to the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.
Specifically <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> for closing an active tab.

When I mapped the key, it said that there were no conflicts with existing key binds, but whenever I try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close an active tab, the "Window" navigation-tab in the editor is selected instead.

(see picture)
[image: as displayed here]

I'm thinking that this is a standard Windows functionality for the navigation tabs in applications which is overriding the Intellij Keymap, but I don't know how to disable this. Any ideas?

Comment: The opening of a menu is standard behaviour in Windows. But if I add Alt-W as a keyboard shortcut for closing the active editor tab, it works without problems on my laptop (with IntelliJ IDEA IC-143.1183.10 on Windows 8.1). When I press Alt-W, the tab is closed and the menu remains unopened. Could you check to make sure your customized keymap is active? When you open the Window | Editor Tabs menu, is the Alt-W keyboard shortcut shown to the right of the Close menu item?

Comment: Thank you Freek, it seems that the Keymapping is not bound at all. When I apply the keymap, the shortcut for Close tab is still the default (CTRL+F4). I am not sure why.. When I reopen the Keymap it does show my customized shortcut, but it does not seem to be activated.

Comment: Which keymap is selected in the settings (for example: "Default copy")? It's possible to have multiple keyboard shortcuts for the same menu item, so both Ctrl-F4 and Alt-W can be linked to the Close item. You could remove the Ctrl-F4 shortcut to make sure. I think only the first shortcut is shown in the menu.

Comment: Thank you Freek de Bruijn! It seems that removing the other shortcut first worked, my alt+w mapping is working correctly now!

Comment: Great! Develop with pleasure... ;-)

Comment: I can't get alt+W to override the window menu. How did you do it? I want to make alt+w do "add to watches". There are no other commands shortcuts for it, so it should work, but does not :(